# How to retreive endpoint of a service

Tags: groovy, soapui

i want to add my project's endpoint in the project tear down script. What is the syntax in order to get the endpoint for all requests and test requests as the user will assign their endpoint via all requests and test requests before running the project?

i seen an example using test step but i don't want to retrieve it via the test step route:

```
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("dd").getHttpRequest().getEndpoint();
```

The tear down script use either , log, context, runner nd project variables.

Thanks

Comment: I believe, endpoint is not really related to project, instead at service or at interface level. Have you looked at here - https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html

Comment: So do you think i need to call on the PServiceEndoint in the script to retrieve it?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Could not get why to reassign the endpoint in tear down of a project?

Comment: Can you remember that test report you created last time. My manager was looking at it and said it was really good that you managed to write that, but she said she likes the url of the service to ensure we are hitting the correct service in the report. So in the report she wants proof that we're hitting the correct endpoint and service in the test report, then the

Comment: Can you show the screen shot of your project? More interested in the number of services / interfaces?

Comment: Screenshots added Rao

Comment: Thank you for the edits with requested information. So, all you need to show is to access the endpoint in the tear down, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the information updated in the question, it looks like you have to access the endpoint in the `TearDown Script` of the project.

It also appears that you would need to execute the same set of tests against different `base url` of the **endpoint** and  **domain**. Not sure even you might need to use the credentials accordingly.

Considering the above, it would be easy to project level properties.

Here you would go:

- Create a project level custom property for **base url**, say `BASE_URL` as property name and value as `http://10.0.0.1:8008`. Of course, change it with actual value as needed with respect to the tests to be executed.
- Similarly create another project level property for **domain**, say `DOMAIN_NAME` and provide its value according the test.
- Double click on service / interface, click on `Service Endpoints` tab.
- Remove all the existing values.
- Add a new endpoint by clicking `+` icon.
- Add `${#Project#BASE_URL}` as endpoint and `${#Project#DOMAIN_NAME}` as domain values
- If required, you use the same approach for the credentials.
- Now click on `Assign` button there and choose `All requests and Tests` option from the dropdown.
- Similarly, do the same if you have multiple services / interfaces.

**How to access the above values in `TearDown Script`?**

```
log.info "Endpoint : ${project.getPropertyValue('BASE_URL')}"
log.info "Domain : ${project.getPropertyValue('DOMAIN_NAME')}"
```

When you want to change `domain` or `base url`, just change the values of the respective project properties before you run execute the tests against different servers / environments.

**EDIT:**

The values for the `endpoint` or `domain` can passed dynamically (without even changing value saved in the project) from command line using `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner` utility while executing the tests. For more details, refer [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html)

Comment: Thank you for sharing Rao. I showed your answer to my manager but she wants to know is there definitly not a way to do this without the tester going in and writing in the endpoints as she prefers the tester to select an already populated endpoint form the list and assign?

Comment: Did not get you. Is it that you want to execute the tests multiple times against each endpoint / domain?

Comment: Virtually the way you have is it correct in terms of the final output, having one endpoint displayed for the whole project, However, she does not want the test to manually type in the endpoint but simply select one from the list. is there a way of doing this?

Comment: That is the way to go. Since it is a property, you can always have different values which is suitable for your current execution without changing anything else.

Comment: I prefer the above because it is clean, you achieve what you wanted and more over you can just change the server details in project property once for the current test. The other way, you know the problem as can't access it and you want to select the one server which is need for particular execution. Using the above approach, you can even pass the endpoint details from command line without even modifying the value in soap project.

Comment: @BruceyBandit, are you still looking for something else?

Comment: Usually how do you execute the tests against multiple servers? one after other server / environment? or do you run in some sort of loop?

Comment: we just run one enivronment at a time and loop through the rest request steps using groovy scripting